Database migration tool for sequelize
I have some experience with database migration in Python, I used Alembic for managing migrations.
On the node.js side we have sequelize which I found it's a nice ORM (good features, etc...), however for managing database migration sequelize-cli gave me quite a bit of headache
My biggest problem is that seqluelize-cli does not autogenerate migration scrips, we are expected to write migration scripts our own, this is not just a hassle but also a large error factor (we have to handle up & down migrations, associations, etc...)
I've looked up for other tools (like Uzmug) but same thing there as well, the migration script must be written by hand. Plan 'B' would be to simply use the built in sequelize.sync({ alter: true}) but this feels scary for production use
Can you please explain the 'right' way to migrate databases for sequelize

After digging, testing, and frustration I got the following outcome
I chose sequelize-cli because it's the most used node migration tool (for sequelize)
1st of all, because sequelize-cli does not support automatic migration script generation I decoupled the project from sequelize-cli, meaning Models are not handled by sequelize-cli.
This approach lead to a new 'feature ', we can use sequelize-cli for any project (Python, .NET, etc...) because it works as a standalone tool now
